# Remove expire attribute in cookies

Tags: c#, cookies, iis-6

Is it possible to remove the Expire attribute from the cookies completely either programmatically in C# or through any tools.

eg output from fiddler:

> Set-Cookie: WSS_KeepSessionAuthenticated=3333; expires=Mon, 06-Oct-2014 09:47:08 GMT; path=/

Required output :

> Set-Cookie: WSS_KeepSessionAuthenticated=3333; path=/

We have done it using URL Rewrite for IIS 7.0. However for IIS 6.0 URL Rewrite seems to insert junk values in the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to give it the following value: `DateTime.MaxValue;` have a look at the following page for the full code:
http://www.dotnetfunda.com/interviews/show/3848/how-can-you-create-a-cookie-that-never-expires
I hope this helps you.

Comment: Setting                                                            Cookie.Expires = DateTime.MaxValue                                            gives the following output in response                             Set-Cookie: mycookie=written 10/7/2014 5:49:44 PM; expires=Fri, 31-Dec-9999 23:59:59 GMT; path=/
Setting it to DateTime.Minvalue did the trick.The output from fiddler:
Set-Cookie: mycookie=written 10/7/2014 5:52:07 PM; path=/                Thanks!!